# Coupon Code throws error when submitting

Tags: cartthrob

I am using Cartthrob 2.5 and EE 2.8.1 and when I use the coupon form from the docs:

```
{exp:cartthrob:add_coupon_form return="cart/view_cart"}
<input type="text" name="coupon_code" />
<input type="submit" name="Add Coupon" />
{/exp:cartthrob:add_coupon_form}
```

EE throws an error:

> The discount code you entered is not valid for any of the items in your cart.

The fields are properly mapped in the CT CP and the coupon entry is set to open without expiration date.

Any setting in CT I might have missed?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Oops, as it turned out you have to specify the product ID in the coupon entry. 
Would be great if the coupon code would apply to all products when left blank.